# How do I pass options to less from git-diff?

Tags: git, git-diff, less-unix

I've got a fairly default setup for git on an OSX machine, but I'd like to add [-j.5](https://superuser.com/questions/257605/how-to-center-search-results-in-less-instead-of-moving-matched-line-to-top-of-t#comment266859_257626) to less, so that search matches happen in the middle of the screen.

I tried doing `export LESS=-j.5`, but that caused content like `ESC[1mdiff --git a/app/images/bluecog-icon.png b/app/images/bluecog-icon.pngESC[m` to appear, even though beforehand, `echo $LESS` gave an empty result. I looked up `git help diff` but it didn't have any mentions of "pager", or mentions of "less" that refer to the unix tool (as opposed to meaning the opposite of "greater").

Either modifying an environmental variable, or passing a parameter to `git diff` is acceptable. I know that I can just input `-j.5` when I'm within git diff itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Git's setup is a bit peculiar:

- The default pager is `less` (though this is a compile-time option).
- You can configure a specific pager with `core.pager`.  If you do this, you can add options here.
- The `less` command itself reads the environment variable `LESS` first, then scans options.
- If the environment variable `LESS` is set (to anything, including even the empty string), Git does not set it; but otherwise, Git sets it to `FRX`, even if the pager is not `less`.

Hence, as noted in [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> ... If you want to selectively override Git's default setting for `LESS`,
>   you can set `core.pager` to e.g. `less -S`. This will be passed to the
>   shell by Git, which will translate the final command to `LESS=FRX less -S`. The environment does not set the `S` option but the command
>   line does, instructing less to truncate long lines. Similarly,
>   setting `core.pager` to `less -+F` will deactivate the `F` option
>   specified by the environment from the command-line, deactivating
>   the "quit if one screen" behavior of `less`. One can specifically
>   activate some flags for particular commands: for example, setting
>   `pager.blame` to `less -S` enables line truncation only for `git blame`.

Hence, if you only want this for `git diff`, set `pager.diff` to `less -j.5`.  If you want it for all Git commands, you can *either* set `core.pager` to `less -j.5` *or* set the environment variable `LESS` to `FRXj.5`; both will have the same effect.

Comment: If you want to set an option globally, you can do something like `git config --global core.pager 'less -i'`, that updates your `~/.gitconfig`

Answer (score 4):

Those `ESC[1m` are color codes for terminal. For `less` to interpret them add option `-R`. Options `-FSX` are also recommended:

```
export LESS=FRSXj.5
```